# How to use GHCi :set args on quoted strings that include functions

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, ghci

I was trying to use GHCi and `:set args` for `main`, as follows:

```
:set args "(\x -> x )"
```

GHCi complains:

```
Couldn't read "\"(\\x -> x )\""as String
```

I don't understand why this can't be treated as a string.
I could do without the quotes:

```
:set args (\x -> x )
```

But apparently, this is incorrect and it would be interpreted as 4 parameters instead of one, as shown by the following `main` function.

```
import System.Environment

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  putStrLn $ show $ length args
```

Any pointers on how to pass this into GHCi?
(I could pass it to compiled ghc code from the command line.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
λ> :set args "(\\x -> x )"
λ> getArgs
["(\\x -> x )"]
```

Note that ghci argument parsing is not the same as shell argument parsing. If you use a string it'll be parsed as a Haskell string.

Another option is to use `withArgs` yourself:

```
λ> withArgs ["(\\x -> x )"] (getArgs >>= mapM_ putStrLn)
(\x -> x )
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what's going on now. It's the escape char.